# Using Python virtualenvs created in host machine on a guest VM

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I have a directory on my host machine which contains a virtualenv. This directory is shared with a virtual machine on which I have to run some Python scripts (contained in the same directory).

When I run Python scripts in the virtualenv on the host machine, the scripts see/use the venv packages without issue. However, when I try to run something in the virtual machine with the same venv activated, Python cannot see the packages.

A workaround would be to create a new virtualenv in the guest machine and use the host's requirements.txt to populate the packages. Another "however": I can't install virtualenv on the guest machine. I run `pip install virtualenv`, it waits for almost a minute, and then I get the following:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for virtualenv
Storing debug log for failure in /home/mininet/.pip/pip.log
```

The important bits from the log are:

```
usr/bin/pip run on Thu Jul 23 03:29:31 2015
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/virtualenv/ (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

FWIW I'm using VirtualBox and the Mininet VM (Ubuntu). The VM can access the Internet.

My primary question, then, is **why can't I use the host venv's packages in the guest machine** even using the same, shared venv?

Two secondary questions are why I can't install virtualenv on the guest machine, and how can I activate the shared venv in the guest machine if the guest doesn't have virtualenv installed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The files in the virtualenv contain absolute file paths that work on the host system but probably not on the guest system. You might be able to fix that by making the virtualenv relocatable (run this on the host system):

```
virtualenv --relocatable ENV
```

More information (and caveats) in the [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#making-environments-relocatable).

Also, you don't mention what the host OS is - as the docs spell out, the virtualenv can only be shared if the OS is the same, because of things like library locations and binary formats.

(I don't have any idea why you can't create the virtualenv on the guest - can you wget https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/ on there?)

Comment: D'oh! One of those things that should have been obvious but was not. Indeed, the host system is OSX and the guest is Ubuntu so even without the path issues it would've been unlikely to work. But `relocatable` is good to know about for the future.

I don't know what was going on with the VM pip yesterday, but after restarting my computer I can install virtualenv and I will start a new virtual environment for the guest. Thanks!

Comment: I find that my VM loses network connectivity if I suspend it on one wireless network and resume it on another - something to do with DHCP, I think. It normally comes back if I restart the VM.